# ORACLE SQL. Count sum values larger than 2 millions within 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find cust_id who made transactions larger than 2 millions within 30 days.

Days are calculated by DATE column.

cust_id ABCD BUY AAA in 2021/10/01 and sell in 2021/10/05, within 4 days, the amt is larger than 2 millions,this is what i want.

cust_id QRST BUY AAA in 2021/10/07 with 900,000 and 100, then sell in 2021/10/07 with 100, within 1 days, but the amt is less than 2 millions, not my result

cust_id ZZYY BUY CCC with 1,000,000 in 2021/10/08 and sell with 1,000,000 in 2021/12/07, amt larger than 2,000,000 but buy date to sell date is longer than 30 days, not my result

| CUST_ID | AMT | DATE | PRD_ID | TRAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 1,000,000 | 2021/10/01 | AAA | BUY |
| ABCD | 1,000,000 | 2021/10/05 | AAA | SELL |
| ABCD | 1,000,000 | 2021/10/06 | BBB | BUY |
| QRST | 900,000 | 2021/10/07 | AAA | BUY |
| QRST | 100 | 2021/10/07 | AAA | BUY |
| QRST | 100 | 2021/10/07 | AAA | SELL |
| ZZYY | 1,000,000 | 2021/10/08 | CCC | BUY |
| ZZYY | 1,000,000 | 2021/12/07 | CCC | SELL |

what i want is

| CUST_ID | AMT | DATE | PRD_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 1,000,000 | 2021/10/01 | AAA |
| ABCD | 1,000,000 | 2021/10/05 | AAA |

Comment: "within 30 days" of what? Also in your sample output, why do you have only the first two rows for customer ABCD, and not all three rows for that customer?

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can find values that are within a 30-day rolling window using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT cust_id,
       amt,
       "DATE",
       prd_id,
       tran,
       match_number
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY cust_id, prd_id
  ORDER     BY "DATE"
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS match_number
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW
  PATTERN (within_30_days* over_2m)
  DEFINE
    within_30_days AS "DATE" <= FIRST("DATE") + INTERVAL '30' DAY,
    over_2m        AS "DATE" <= FIRST("DATE") + INTERVAL '30' DAY
                      AND SUM(amt) >= 2000000
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (CUST_ID, AMT, "DATE", PRD_ID, TRAN) AS
SELECT 'ABCD', 1000000, DATE '2021-10-01', 'AAA', 'BUY'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD', 1000000, DATE '2021-10-05', 'AAA', 'SELL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD', 1000000, DATE '2021-10-06', 'BBB', 'BUY'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'QRST',  900000, DATE '2021-10-07', 'AAA', 'BUY'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'QRST',     100, DATE '2021-10-07', 'AAA', 'BUY'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'QRST',     100, DATE '2021-10-07', 'AAA', 'SELL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZZYY', 1000000, DATE '2021-10-08', 'CCC', 'BUY'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZZYY', 1000000, DATE '2021-12-07', 'CCC', 'SELL' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUST_ID | AMT | DATE | PRD_ID | TRAN | MATCH_NUMBER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ABCD | 1000000 | 01-OCT-21 | AAA | BUY | 1 |
> | ABCD | 1000000 | 05-OCT-21 | AAA | SELL | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2664782fa1a0a33c0f8e2fd4b77e460)*

Answer (score 0):

You updated the question later. Hence, I am answering again based upon more information.

```
WITH buy_date AS (
    SELECT
        b.cust_id,
        b.date,
        b.prd_id
    FROM
        table_name b
    WHERE
            b.tran = 'BUY'
        AND b.amt > 2000000
), sell_date AS (
    SELECT
        s.cust_id,
        s.date,
        s.prd_id
    FROM
        table_name s
    WHERE
            s.tran = 'SELL'
        AND s.amt > 2000000
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    buy_date   bd,
    sell_date  sd
WHERE
        bd.cust_id = sd.cust_id
    AND bd.prd_id = sd.prd_id
    AND sd.date - bd.date <= 30;
```